# How to make UI of Button like This in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, user-interface, mobile, uibutton

i want to make ui of this button like this, and it will supports all the iphone and ipad screen

[image]

Comment: Use transparent background image for button.

Comment: Add a CAGradientLayer to the button and set its `colors` and `locations` properties.

Answer (score 3):

You can use CAGradientLayer. Although the result is not exactly the same, it has advantages over setting a background image when the button size changes.

The code below is ready for Xcode Playground:

```
import UIKit

let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 30))
button.setTitle("Order", for: .normal)
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray

let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.frame = button.bounds
gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5) //Set the start point to the left edge center
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5) //Set end point to the right edge center
gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor, UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor]
gradientLayer.locations = [0, 0.2, 0.8, 1] //At the start point, the clear color is used; at 20% horizontal, red is used, etc

button.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
button
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks ...i have made little change then it willl worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Little Change in the code with **Swift 2.3**

button.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()

```
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = button.bounds
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5) //Set the start point to the left edge center
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5) //Set end point to the right edge center
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.clearColor().CGColor, UIColor.redColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5).CGColor, UIColor.redColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5).CGColor, UIColor.clearColor().CGColor]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0, 0.2, 0.8, 1] //At the start point, the clear color is used; at 20% horizontal, red is used, etc

    button.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, atIndex: 0)
```